# How to know child window is open or closed ? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, window

In WPF, How do I know if a child window is opened ?
my goal is to open only one instance of the window at the same time..

Here is pseudo code in the parent window

```
if (newWindowIsOpened)    //just a pseudo code
{
newWindow.Close();
newWindow.Show();
}
else{
newWindow.Show();
}
```

thanks In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In WPF, How do I know if a child window is opened

Look for it in `Application.Current.Windows`:

```
var oldWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<YourWindowType>().FirstOrDefault();
if (oldWindow != null)
{
    oldWindow .close();
}
YourWindowType newWindow = new YourWindowType();
newWindow.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add below code

public bool newWindowIsOpened;

```
    public Window14()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Window1 window1 = new Window1();
        window1.Closed += new EventHandler(window1_Closed);
        newWindowIsOpened = false;
        window1.Show();
    }

    void window1_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newWindowIsOpened = true;
    }
```

Thanks,
Ajay Dubedi

Comment: Thanks, But I Have Button Click event.. If user request for that specific new window I needed to close it first (if it is already open) and then open new window.. actually I can have dynamic content for each new window which is to be opened.. That's what I'm looking for

Comment: this answer is fully compatible with you request you just need to add a few lines to close and reopen the window

Answer (score 0):

Once a window has been closed you can't show it again. You can repeatedly call `Show()` and `Hide()` though, and you can test if it's "open" by checking `IsVisible`

Comment: Thanks, And you are right... once a window has been closed, can't show it again..
But I need to put this code on a button click event.. If user request for that specific window I needed to close it first (if it is already open) and then open new window.. actually I can have dynamic content for each new window which is being opened.. That's what I'm looking for

Comment: That's fine, if it's open then IsVisible will be true, it doesn't get set until you call Show().

Comment: But how to make check (by parent window) whether new window is open or not already  ?

Comment: You mean after you call `Show()`? Subscribe to the `Loaded`event. Window initialization doesn't happen right away, so you have to subscribe to the callback event.